# JavaScript Tabs - Show only when all images are loaded

Tags: javascript, image, tabs, load

-Hello can someone pls help me with this:

I need to fix this issue: I have a JavaScript Tab, but it only displays correctly once the images on another java script (jquery) are fully loaded.

I experimented with the document ready function but no effect is taking place.

```
 <!-- Tabs -->
<script src="tabs.js"></script>
<script>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" );
    });
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: try and put the code without document.ready.. just after the tabs html so that it loads sooner

Comment: can you can show a fiddle of the issue

Comment: hello, pls. go to http://www.schreiber-filderstadt.com/rundschweissautomaten.html

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ktk4E/    here is the tab.js which is external.. maybe someone can modify it and make it work that way?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style = "display:none" id = "tabs">
```

JS

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();

$( document ).ready(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).show();
});
```

Why not just hide the tabs and then show them when the document is ready?

Comment: Hello, I did not manage to get it done with your assistance. can you pls check out http://www.schreiber-filderstadt.com/rundschweissautomaten.html and see the wholte HTML..